# How to post data to HTML using Express.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sqlite, mustache

I'm finishing a project from my dev bootcamp course and I'm having trouble posting new data to my html via form. I have the HTML all setup, but whenever I post new data, nothing shows! I also want the page to be redirected to a specific topic.

app.js

```
app.get('/comments/new', function(req, res){
res.send(fs.readFileSync('./views/comments/newComment.html', 'utf8'));
});


app.post('/topics/:id', function(req, res){
var id = req.params.id;
console.log(req.body);
db.run("INSERT INTO comments(person_created, input) VALUES ('" + req.body.person_created + "','" + req.body.input + "')");
res.redirect("/topics/ "  + id)

});

app.get('/topics/:id', function(req, res){
var id = req.params.id;

db.all("SELECT * FROM topics WHERE id = " + id + ";", {}, function(err, topic){
    console.log(topic)

    var body = topic.body;

db.all("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE topic_id = " + id + ";", {}, function(err, comment){

    var person_created = comment.person_created;
    var input = comment.input

    fs.readFile('./views/topics/show.html', 'utf8', function(err, html){
        var renderedHTML = Mustache.render(html, {body:topic, person_created:comment, input:comment});
        res.send(renderedHTML);
        console.log(comment);

    });
    });
});
});
```

schema.js

```
var sqlite3 = require ('sqlite3');
var db = new sqlite3.Database('./forum.db');


db.serialize(function(){
db.run("CREATE TABLE topics(id integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT, title  varchar, creator varchar, date varchar, body varchar);")
db.run("CREATE TABLE comments(person_created varchar, input varchar, topic_id integer, FOREIGN KEY (topic_id) references topics(id));")

db.parallelize(function(){
db.run("INSERT INTO topics(title, creator, date, body) VALUES ('Top R&B Hits of the 80s', 'Michael', '4/15/15', 'Please share some of your favorite R&B Hits from the decade!' );")
db.run("INSERT INTO comments(person_created, input, topic_id) VALUES ('Sheila', 'Bille Jean by Michael Jackson', 1);")
db.run("INSERT INTO comments(person_created, input, topic_id) VALUES ('George ', 'Gett Outta of My Dreams by Billy Ocean', 1); ")
   });
   });
```

newComment.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
     <style type="text/css">
    body{
    background-color: gray;

     }
      </style>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <title>Create New Comment</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action="/topics/:id" method="POST">

<center>

<label>

    Name:
      <br />
      <input type="text" name="name" rows="10" cols="50" />
</label>

<label>

       <br />
       <p></p>

    Comment:

       <br />

       <textarea type="text" name="name" rows="10" cols="50">
       </textarea>
       </label>
       <br />
        <button>Submit</button>
        </center>
  </form>
  </body>
  </html>
```

show.html

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang='en'>
  <head>
  <style type="text/css">
  body{
  background-image: url("http://blog.paradizo.com/wp- content/uploads/2010/03/nyc-empire-room.jpg");
   background-position: center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-attachment: fixed;
   background-size: 100% auto;

   }


   </style>
   <meta charset='UTF-8'>
   <title>Topic ID</title>
   </head>
   <body>
   <center>

  {{#body}}
  <h1>{{body}}</h1>
  {{/body}}


 <h2>Comments<h2>

 <h3>
 <ol>
 {{#person_created}}
 <li>
 {{person_created}} - {{input}}

 </li>
 {{/person_created}}
 </ol>
 </h3>







<form action="/comments/new" method='GET'>
<button>Create New Comment</button>
</form>
</center>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you using middleware to parse the forms (e.g. `body-parser`'s `urlencoded()` middleware)?

Comment: Please format your code with proper indentation in your question.  It is not very easy to read/follow it with improper indentation.

Comment: @jfriend00 Which code are you referring to?

Comment: All the code you posted in your question, particularly the .js files.

Comment: @jfriend00 Everything should be readable now

Comment: @middleware No I'm not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending `POST` data with your form to `/topics/:id` for the `POST` router on `/topics/:id`. You should `POST` to the URL with the ID that you want to use for the logic in your router. This ID will then be available via `req.params.id`.

When you are rendering the page with your form, you can pass the current ID as a local variable using `res.locals`, then use this dynamic local variable to construct your form `action` attribute. This will then pass the correct ID to your router via `req.params`.

As a side note, you are attempting to access `person_created` and `input` on `req.body`, but the inputs from your form are only available by their `name` input values. Your `name` values are currently both `name`. You should name them `uniquely` and ensure you have `body-parser` middleware enabled.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I have body-parser enabled already because I am able to post new topics and display on html. I have already changed the input values like you mentioned and still nothing works.  I want all the comments posted to each topic id.

Comment: Were you able to change your form `action` value to reflect the current ID instead of requesting to `/topics/:id`?

Comment: No and I'm confused. I have tried setting the form action values to '/topics', '/comments/new'.

Comment: You need to set the `action` value to post to `/topics/:id` where `:id` is the ID of what you are interested in. This will then expose the variable to your `POST` router and make it available via `req.params.id`. The `:id` part of your router is a wildcard that depends on whatever appears in that portion of the URL for a `POST` request to that URL. You could pass the ID when you are rendering the form using `res.locals.id = currentID` or something similar, and then use that variable to make the `action` URL for your form. It would look something like `form action='/topics/' + id` in this case.

Comment: Then I should set the form action value and app.post to topics/:id and create a variable id=req.locals.id?

Comment: The form `action` is the URL that the form will send a request to, in this case with `POST` HTML headers. This will trigger a router in your web application if you have configured an appropriate router for the URL. The `:id` should only be used in your router. It is only used a way to dynamically represent the value of that portion of the URL so that you can access it with `req.params.id`. If your router was for `/topics/:group` then it would be available in `req.params.group` for requests like `/topics/myGroup`. I suggested to use `res.locals.id = currentID` to create an appropriate `action`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107055/discussion-between-michael-stokes-and-roflmyeggo).

Comment: I'm still having no luck. So far I did res.locals.id = 'id'. I set the form action to 'topics\{{#id}. I was able to have it redirected to the topics page but not the topic id page. I also did res.render(newComments.html) and I got errors saying can't find html module.

Comment: You need to make sure that you are directing to the correct URL from your form. It looks like `{{#id}}` isn't the correct way to render the `res.locals` variable in your HTML preprocessor. You need to look in the documentation to figure out the correct syntax. Once you have the correct action value of the form then you can worry about the next step.

Comment: I found something about res.locals but it doesn't seem to help me solve my problem.

Comment: Try `{{id}}` and see if that works. You can find the generalized documentation for Mustache here: https://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html

Comment: Well after I posted it went straight back to the list of topics but no id#

Comment: Your local variables should be set like `res.locals.id = req.params.id` because `id` is not a variable in that router path.

Comment: I have tried doing that but see the syntax below. See where 'id' is? Right now a variable has been created for that. If I do res.locals.id = res.params.id, that 'id' variable will become undefined. 

var id = req.params.id; 

res.locals.id = "id"

db.all("SELECT * FROM topics WHERE id = " + id + ";", {}, function(err, topic){ 
console.log(topic) 

var body = topic.body; 

db.all("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE topic_id = " + id + ";", {}, function(err, comment){ 

var person_created = comment.person_created; 
var input = comment.input

That's how I got it setup now

Comment: If you have `var id = req.params.id;` than you can do `res.locals.id = id;` but not `res.locals.id = "id";`. Those are two different things. Once you have that, then if your id variable is not showing up in your template you need to debug why that is happening and go from there.

Comment: Okay. Don't I also need to do a mustache.render?

Comment: Yes, that renders the view to your HTML response and passes local variables. You could pass the `id` variable here instead if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Your form action should not be /topics/:id since :id is a parameter value calculated by express, so you would pass in the actual value.

So if your form action is /topics/505 then 505 will be the value of req.params.id

Comment: I want to add, as a meta to the answer, that when adding a new value via post it is best practice to generate the id value on the server (preferably by the database primary key auto-increment).  So in that case you would change your form action and post url to /topics - this will simplify things for you in the future.

Comment: @michael-stokes does this answer your question? If so, please consider accepting the answer.  If not, please let me know and I will help further.

Comment: No. I'll need further help.